# Convert TableViewController to ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have started with a TableViewController but now I would like to change from a TableViewController to a ViewController in the storyboard. Is there an easy way to do this? I want to avoid creating a new View scene in the storyboard and copying the code over.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the current TableViewController and create a new ViewController.

If you will set an TableView inside, you also must set DataSource/Delegate, and conform with the Table Views protocols in the ViewController Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ContainerView. Take one UIViewController and add a ContainerView inside it. Control drag from the ContainerView to TableViewController and select EmbedIn. This is the only way to keep existing TableViewController, but you need to move your code from TableViewController to ViewController. Do this only if it is necessary to use TableViewController and you have to display a View outside the TableView.

Answer (score 0):

Just start implementing ViewController protocol and remove TableViewController, TableViewControllerDelegate and TableViewControllerDataSource.

Also remove the methods from the TableViewDataSource and that's it.